# How to set module search path in GCC?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20

I know that ~fprebuilt-module-path` can set the module search path in clang, but how to set module search path in GCC?

Comment: I don't think GCC has a direct equivalent to that option. I suspect the right way to go about it is to [set up a module mapping file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper.html#C_002b_002b-Module-Mapper) or a mapper, with the former possibly being generated by something like CMake rather than manually.